# Existence of common convergent subsequence indexes for infinite number of sequences in a compact metric space.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, compactness

A slight infinite extension of this
[Show that two bounded sequences have convergent subsequences with the same index sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595748/show-that-two-bounded-sequences-have-convergent-subsequences-with-the-same-index)

Let $S$ be a compact metric space. Suppose, for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$,  $\{x(m,n)\}_{n\geq 1}$, is a sequence in $S$.
The question is can we always get a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $n_k, k=1,2,\cdots$ such that the subsequence for each $m$, $\{x(m,n_k)\}_{k\geq 1}$ is convergent as $k\to \infty$? I want the same $n_k$ working for any $m$.

I worked like this:

Compact implies sequentially compact in metric spaces. Therefore, the sequence for fixed $m$, $\{x(m,n)\}_{n\geq 1}$ has convergent subsequence. But the subsequence indices would differ for each $m$. I am not able to move further inductively.
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: A “diagonal argument” as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288007/countable-product-of-sequentially-compact-spaces-is-sequentially-compact should work.

Comment: Thanks!! Good work..